# Pass an Mock object to class

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, mstest, rhino-mocks

In below code block i need to use the object of class RETTemplateLoader(created as "obiz") inside method of "obizEmail.GetEmailContent", hence i created the Mock for class BizCampaignEmailSend(created as "obizEmail") but i don't find how to link this two objects so that while the method "GetEmailContent" gets invoked, i'm expecting it return `"<HTML>"`(my hard coded text)

```
<TestMethod(), Owner("TestEmail"), TestCategory("Testing")> _
    Public Sub GetEmailContent()
        Using oClass As New SessionClass("UnitTesting", Me.GetType.Name)
            Dim oSvcJPEmailProductsCampaignStruct As New SvcJPEmailProductsCampaignStruct
            'Class obj 1
            Dim obiz = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock(Of RETTemplateLoader)(New Object() {"", "", "", False})
            obiz.Stub(Function(c) c.LoadEmailTemplateNew(oClass)).Return("<HTML>")
            'Class obj 2
            Dim obizEmail = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock(Of BizCampaignEmailSend)()
            Assert.AreEqual(obizEmail.GetEmailContent(oClass , oSvcJPEmailProductsCampaignStruct), "<HTML>")
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Here is my method which i need to give test coverage

```
Public Overridable Function GetEmailContent(ByVal oClass As SessionClass, ByVal oCampaignStruct As SvcJPEmailProductsCampaignStruct) As String          
    Dim sEmailTemplate As String = String.Empty
    Dim oRETTemplateLoader As New RETTemplateLoader(oCampaignStruct.CampaignContent, "",    oCampaignStruct.AutoResponseDID, True)
    sEmailTemplate = oRETTemplateLoader.LoadEmailTemplateNew(oClass)
    Return sEmailTemplate
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to do any linking here. You don't need to call your SUT (System Under Test) as mock object in this case. I don't see benefit of setting up a stub for returning "" by invoking

> oRETTemplateLoader.LoadEmailTemplateNew(oClass)

and then having a mock object for your SUT which calls the above method and expecting it to return what you have mocked already. Your SUT doesn't have much behaviour.

The only thing I would suggest it to verify whether the oRETTemplateLoader.LoadEmailTemplateNew(oClass) is called.

Something like below. (Note I'm not VB.NET expert but you should be able to fix any syntax errors. I 'll just show my intention.)

```
 <TestMethod(), Owner("TestEmail"), TestCategory("Testing")> _
Public Sub GetEmailContent()
    Using oClass As New SessionClass("UnitTesting", Me.GetType.Name)
        Dim oSvcJPEmailProductsCampaignStruct As New SvcJPEmailProductsCampaignStruct
        'Set your expectation
        Dim obiz = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock(Of RETTemplateLoader)(New Object() {"", "", "", False})
        obiz.Expect(Function(c) c.LoadEmailTemplateNew(oClass)).Return("some string")

        'Call SUT
        Dim sut As New BizCampaignEmailSend
        Dim r = sut.GetEmailContent(oClass , oSvcJPEmailProductsCampaignStruct)

         'Verify
         obiz.VerifyAllExpectations()
    End Using
End Sub
```